# What's the difference between tesseract and Tessnet?

Tags: c#, .net, ocr, tesseract, tessnet2

I have been looking for a tutorial or a some guidance as to how to setup tesseract or tessnet and the tesseract wiki says only about training tesseract 3.01 or 2.0x. Can I know what the difference between tessnet and tesseract?  And which one should i use on a c# application? after training which files should i use for the ocr part?

I am really looking forward an answer as I posted a few questions on this but I haven't been able to get a proper answer or I have not been able to find a complete guidance on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tesseract is an OCR engine written in C++. Tessnet2 is a C# wrapper for Tesseract. I am building a WPF OCR application and I am using Tessnet2 so I can write it in C# without making my own wrapper.

TessNet2 is based on Tesseract v2.04 and has not been updated since September 2009. Tesseract is continually being updated and is now on version 3.01 (3.02 is available but not officially released). But TessNet2 includes everything I need.